# Selling Partner API AMAZON (SP API) - Listings Items API returns 403 forbidden

Tags: postman, amazon-selling-partner-api

I have a problem that's bothering me, I'll tell you.

All this has been done from the Postman App

I am trying to access, through the SP API, the Amazon products (in this case those of my seller profile to update the stock) but still authorizing and obtaining my access tokens as the documentation dictates, I still get this response:

```json
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "Unauthorized",
            "message": "Access to requested resource is denied.",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

On the other hand, I have been able to access the orders API using the same authentication.

In conclusion, I have a couple of doubts. I am pending the verification of the access form necessary to access some extra parts of the API, so perhaps this part needs that permission to access the resources.

Or maybe doubting me, the product API needs some more step to verify authentication.

My final endpoint looks like this:

```
{{host}}/catalog/2020-12-01/items/:asin?marketplaceIds={{marketplaceId}}&includedData=summaries
```

Any useful information you can provide would be of great help as the documentation is not entirely good.

I have tried to solve it through the official documentation, following the necessary steps. In addition to reviewing the videos there are about it, but there are not many since it is quite specific content.

Comment: "been able to access the orders API using the same authentication." .. you have?  How?  You said it is giving you this .. "Unauthorized" ... so if you think the credentials are correct because you tested them outside the API .. then perhaps your implentation into the script is the issue?

Comment: The order API accepts the request, the product API rejects it with a 403.

Comment: Ahh okay, update the question with that information ,  something on the product API needs some configs to accept the order API request if its not authorized to send requests to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you authorized 'product listing' on your API and developer profile? I had the same issue. After it authorized, it worked for me.

Comment: Yes, we have the option activated both in the developer profile and in the API.